# In a file system, keep going up levels until a specific directory is reached

Tags: python, file, directory

I am working on a project with multiple folders, subfolders, etc in python.
I have to access the files or libraries stored outside of my pwd, but inside the main directory of the project.
I would like to use relative paths while referring to directory names throughout the project.
A problem that I come across is as:
I may sometimes open up vscode in one folder or its sub folder. But I want to access the files in a different folder, for which i will have to go either one or two levels above my pwd, and then into the required folder.
I want my code to be written such that it is independent of which directory I make my pwd, as long as it is within the main directory of the project.

how do I write code that does this to, say, access a folder ?
I would use a loop and a conditional statement, going up a level until I reach the required directory. But this feels not-as-elegant. Is there a better or more pythonic way to do this ?

I would use a loop and a conditional statement, going up a level until I reach the required directory. But this feels not-as-elegant. Is there a better or more pythonic way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact file hierarchy, but I'll assume it is something like the following *without loss of generality*:

```
ProjectRoot
|- Main.py
|-- SomeDir
|   |- Subdir
|-- Config
    |- main.txt
```

If you call Main.py from **any** working directory on your machine, you can get the absolute path of Main.py's parent directory by calling the following in Main.py:

```py
# Main.py
import pathlib
absolute_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
```

From there, you can access all files by simply concatenating their relative path to your projects root:

```py
config_path = absolute_path + "/Config/main.txt"

with open(config_path, "r") as f:
    print(f.readlines())
```

Comment: In my own case, the file I am writing the code in is in Subdir, but I get the general idea. Thanks a lot!